# Scorm files, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scorm

I have implemented a scorm api in my platform (LMS), for this I have used Ruby on rails, the Scorm gem and the javascript api.
Everything works correctly and the scorm contents are displayed with satisfaction. I do not have much experience in Scorm content, but there is a zip file that they sent me of type scorm, which when it is uploaded to the platform that I am using, it takes a long time to load and execute. when I test this file on Scorm cloud, the content runs normally. The problem is that the platform does not generate any error.

why can this happen?
bugs in my code? or optimization of the Scorm zip file?
The other scorm contents work normally, but this specific one, I have no idea why. I can not think of anything

any ideas? Thank you

this is de api js:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>VS SCORM - RTE API</title>

<script language="javascript">

function createRequest() {

  // this is the object that we're going to (try to) create
  var request;

  // does the browser have native support for
  // the XMLHttpRequest object
  try {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

  // it failed so it's likely to be Internet Explorer which
  // uses a different way to do this
  catch (tryIE) {

    // try to see if it's a newer version of Internet Explorer
    try {
      request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }

    // that didn't work so ...
    catch (tryOlderIE) {

      // maybe it's an older version of Internet Explorer
      try {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      // even that didn't work (sigh)
      catch (failed) {
        alert("Error creating XMLHttpRequest");
      }

    }
  }

  return request;

}

//var debug = true;
var debug = false;

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

// ------------------------------------------
//   SCORM RTE Functions - Initialization
// ------------------------------------------

function LMSInitialize(dummyString) {
    // create request object
    var req = createRequest();

    // code to prevent caching
    var d = new Date();

    // set up request parameters - uses GET method
    req.open('GET','/scorm/initializesco?code='+d.getTime(),false);

    // submit to the server for processing
    req.send(null);

    // process returned data - error condition
    if (req.status != 200) {
        alert('Problem with Request');
        return "";
    }

    // process returned data - OK
    else {
        return "true";
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------
//   SCORM RTE Functions - Getting and Setting Values
// ------------------------------------------
//function LMSGetValue(varname) {
//  if (debug) {
//    alert('*** LMSGetValue varname='+varname
//                          +' varvalue=value ***');
//  }
//  return "value";
//}
function LMSGetValue(varname) {
  // create request object
  var req = createRequest();

  // set up request parameters - uses GET method
  req.open('GET','/scorm/getValue?varname='+urlencode(varname)
          +'&code='+Math.random(),false);

  // submit to the server for processing
  req.send(null);

  //alert('LMSGetValue() - ' + req.responseText);

  // process returned data - error condition
  if (req.status != 200) {
    alert('LMSGetValue() - Problem with Request');
    return "";
  }

  // process returned data - OK
  else {
    return req.responseText.replace("\n","");
  }
}
/*
function LMSSetValue(varname,varvalue) {
  if (debug) {
    alert('*** LMSSetValue varname='+varname
                          +' varvalue='+varvalue+' ***');
  }
  return "true";
}
*/

function LMSSetValue(varname,varvalue) {

  // create request object
  var req = createRequest();

  // set up request parameters - uses combined GET and POST
  //req.open('POST','nav/setValue?varname='+urlencode(varname)
  //      +'&code='+Math.random(),false);

  // set up request parameters - uses combined GET and POST
  req.open('POST','/scorm/setValue?varname='+urlencode(varname)
        +'&code='+Math.random(),false);

  // send header information along with the POST data
  var params = 'varvalue='+urlencode(varvalue);
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
             "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  //req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
  //req.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

  // submit to the server for processing
  req.send(params);

  // process returned data - error condition
  if (req.status != 200) {
    alert('LMSSetValue() - Problem with Request');
    return "false";
  }

  // process returned data - OK
  else {
    return "true";
  }

}

function LMSCommit(dummyString) {
    LMSGetValue('');
    if (debug)
    {
        //alert('*** LMSCommit ***');
    }
    return "true";
}

function LMSFinish(dummyString) {
    // create request object
    var req = createRequest();

    // code to prevent caching
    var d = new Date();

    // set up request parameters - uses GET method
    req.open('GET','/scorm/finishsco?code='+d.getTime(),false);

    // submit to the server for processing
    req.send(null);

    // process returned data - error condition
    if (req.status != 200) {
        alert('Problem with Request');
        return "";
    }

    // process returned data - OK
    else {
        return "true";
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------
//   SCORM RTE Functions - Error Handling
// ------------------------------------------
function LMSGetLastError() {
  if (debug) { alert('*** LMSGetLastError ***'); }

  sleep(1000);

  return 0;
}

function LMSGetDiagnostic(errorCode) {
  if (debug) {
    alert('*** LMSGetDiagnostic errorCode='+errorCode+' ***');
  }
  return "diagnostic string";
}

function LMSGetErrorString(errorCode) {
  if (debug) {
    alert('*** LMSGetErrorString errorCode='+errorCode+' ***');
  }
  return "error string";
}


function urlencode( str ) {
  //
  // Ref: http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/javascript_equivalent_for_phps_urlencode/
  //
    var histogram = {}, unicodeStr='', hexEscStr='';
    var ret = (str+'').toString();

    var replacer = function(search, replace, str) {
        var tmp_arr = [];
        tmp_arr = str.split(search);
        return tmp_arr.join(replace);
    };

    // The histogram is identical to the one in urldecode.
    histogram["'"]   = '%27';
    histogram['(']   = '%28';
    histogram[')']   = '%29';
    histogram['*']   = '%2A';
    histogram['~']   = '%7E';
    histogram['!']   = '%21';
    histogram['%20'] = '+';
    histogram['\u00DC'] = '%DC';
    histogram['\u00FC'] = '%FC';
    histogram['\u00C4'] = '%D4';
    histogram['\u00E4'] = '%E4';
    histogram['\u00D6'] = '%D6';
    histogram['\u00F6'] = '%F6';
    histogram['\u00DF'] = '%DF';
    histogram['\u20AC'] = '%80';
    histogram['\u0081'] = '%81';
    histogram['\u201A'] = '%82';
    histogram['\u0192'] = '%83';
    histogram['\u201E'] = '%84';
    histogram['\u2026'] = '%85';
    histogram['\u2020'] = '%86';
    histogram['\u2021'] = '%87';
    histogram['\u02C6'] = '%88';
    histogram['\u2030'] = '%89';
    histogram['\u0160'] = '%8A';
    histogram['\u2039'] = '%8B';
    histogram['\u0152'] = '%8C';
    histogram['\u008D'] = '%8D';
    histogram['\u017D'] = '%8E';
    histogram['\u008F'] = '%8F';
    histogram['\u0090'] = '%90';
    histogram['\u2018'] = '%91';
    histogram['\u2019'] = '%92';
    histogram['\u201C'] = '%93';
    histogram['\u201D'] = '%94';
    histogram['\u2022'] = '%95';
    histogram['\u2013'] = '%96';
    histogram['\u2014'] = '%97';
    histogram['\u02DC'] = '%98';
    histogram['\u2122'] = '%99';
    histogram['\u0161'] = '%9A';
    histogram['\u203A'] = '%9B';
    histogram['\u0153'] = '%9C';
    histogram['\u009D'] = '%9D';
    histogram['\u017E'] = '%9E';
    histogram['\u0178'] = '%9F';

    // Begin with encodeURIComponent, which most resembles PHP's encoding functions
    ret = encodeURIComponent(ret);

    for (unicodeStr in histogram) {
        hexEscStr = histogram[unicodeStr];
        ret = replacer(unicodeStr, hexEscStr, ret); // Custom replace. No regexing
    }

    // Uppercase for full PHP compatibility
    return ret.replace(/(\%([a-z0-9]{2}))/g, function(full, m1, m2) {
        return "%"+m2.toUpperCase();
    });
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using blocking GET/SET requests (XHR async=false) to your backend for every LMSGetValue call.  Some courses are much more aggressive about how many things they get and set at launch/initialization time.  Most SCORM implementations do the heavy lifting in JS (all GET value processing never touches a server, most commonly) and only go to the backend for user state storage, often at a commit or some storage frequency.  If that's the issue, there's no way to fix it that doesn't involve rewriting your interface to do all the SCORM logic client-side instead of server-side, as you can't switch to using async GET calls since LMSGetValue expects the return to be the value needed.